# Comparing values of type DATE - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Is there any way of comparing to date values to check if one is before the other? 
For example how do i know which came first on the following rows

```
SEQ   CREATION_DTM
--------------------
234   2011-03-26 22:59:03
235   2011-03-26 22:59:03
```

The column for the above data is declarad as datatype DATE. Having read around it appears that the DATE datatype does not store milliseconds. Does this mean 
i cant compare the above two dates to find out which one is before the other?

### EDIT

I am using Oracle 10G on Solaris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DATE only stores up to the second.  So if two rows are inserted in the same second, you can't determine which came first based on the `CREATION_DTM` column.  If you want that level of resolution, you'd be better served with a `TIMESTAMP [WITH [LOCAL] TIME ZONE]` column which will store the time component up to 9 decimal digits if the host operating system provides that level of granularity (most Unix systems will provide microsecond resolution).

In your case, assuming that you're not using RAC and that you are using an Oracle sequence to populate the `SEQ` column, you could use that column to break the tie.  If the two rows were inserted in different transactions, haven't been updated, and the table was built with `ROWDEPENDENCIES`, you could also potentially use the `ORA_ROWSCN` to break the tie.

Comment: Can rowid be used to check which row was inserted first?

Comment: @Ziggy - No.  A ROWID is a physical address.  There is no reason the expect that physical order of rows in a table will match the order in which rows are inserted particularly if rows are ever deleted or updated.

Answer (score 5):

[`DATE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref116) precision only goes to the nearest second, so if you have two dates that are the same to that precision then you can't distinguish between or order them. To get any more precision you'd need to store them as [`TIMESTAMP`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i53219).

In the more general case where the dates do differ you can compare and order them much like numbers. When you get two the same the results are uncertain; in you case if you ordered by `CREATION_DTM` then you couldn't reliably predict whether the results would be ordered as `234,235` or `235,234`. You would need to determine a way to break a tie, as Justin has suggested.

Comment: The race is half the fun. Despite usually losing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems timestamp data type will be appropriate for you query..
Thanks